# Data-augmentation giving me worse results

Tags: keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, mnist

I used Keras ImageDataGenerator and passed my training images thought it (MNIST dataset).

```
datagen=keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
featurewise_center=True,
samplewise_center=True,
featurewise_std_normalization=True,                                     
samplewise_std_normalization=True,rotation_range=10,                                                    
width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1,zoom_range=0.1,
shear_range=0.01,validation_split=0.1
)

datagen.fit(X_train)
train_gen=datagen.flow(X_train,y_train.toarray(),batch_size=32,subset='training')
validation_gen=datagen.flow(X_val,y_val.toarray(),batch_size=32,subset='validation')

lrate=keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)

model_history=model.fit_generator(train_gen,epochs=50,verbose=2,validation_data=validation_gen,callbacks=[lrate])
```

[image]

While training I get the results that are expected and get a validation score above 99%. Here's the graph after training:

But when I used `model.evaluate` to get scores in for the validation dataset I get a very low score

```
scores = model.evaluate(X_val,y_val.toarray(), verbose = 10 )
print (scores)
```

I get result as:

> [2.454622192836943, 0.080714285]

- Why is this happening?
- How to pass the images through datagen at test time?

Answer (score 0):

In training, you got the images from `train_gen`, so in validation you should get them from `validation_gen`, not from `X_val` and `y_val` as you have.

Any pre-processing done for training should typically also be done before inference. Use `model.evaluate_generator(validation_gen)` as per [this documentation.](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate_generator)